# SparkContext Parallelize splits on wrong places

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I downloaded a file and now I'm trying to write it as a dataframe to hdfs.

```
import requests
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Write Data').setMaster('local')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

file = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.csv')

data = sc.parallelize(file)
```

When I print the content of my file I see the following output:

```
print(file.text)
":@computed_region_cbhk_fwbd",":@computed_region_nnqa_25f4","fall","geolocation","geolocation_address","geolocation_city","geolocation_state","geolocation_zip","id","mass","name","nametype","recclass","reclat","reclong","year"
,,"Fell","POINT (6.08333 50.775)",,,,,"1","21","Aachen","Valid","L5","50.775000","6.083330","1880-01-01T00:00:00.000"
,,"Fell","POINT (10.23333 56.18333)",,,,,"2","720","Aarhus","Valid","H6","56.183330","10.233330","1951-01-01T00:00:00.000"
```

And that is exactly what I want to see. Now I'm trying to take the header from  my RDD that was created using `data = sc.parallelize(file)`

```
print(data.first())
":@computed_region_cbhk_fwbd",":@computed_region_nnqa_25f4","fall","geolocation","geolocation_address","geolocation_city","geolo
```

Why am I not getting the first line like I was expecting from my first print? It stopped somewhere halfway and I'm not seeing the other components of my header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `Response.__iter__` is not format aware. It just [iterates over fixed size chunks](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/205755834d34a8a6ecf2b0b5b2e9c3e6a7f4e4b6/requests/models.py#L683-L685).

If you really have to read data like this use `text.splitlines`:

```
sc.parallelize(file.text.splitlines())
```

or better:

```
import csv
import io

sc.parallelize(csv.reader(io.StringIO(file.text)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple. To parallelise the Python object, you need to supply a list to Spark. In this case you are supplying a response:

```
>>> file = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.csv')
>>> file
<Response [200]>
```

If you extract the data, and you will help Spark by splitting this yourself, Spark will understand it:

```
import requests
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Write Data').setMaster('local')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

file = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.csv').text.split('\n')

data = sc.parallelize(file)
data.first()
>>> u'":@computed_region_cbhk_fwbd",":@computed_region_nnqa_25f4","fall","geolocation","geolocation_address","geolocation_city","geolocation_state","geolocation_zip","id","mass","name","nametype","recclass","reclat","reclong","year"'
```

When you have a filesystem like Hadoop, hadoop will do the splitting for you and arrange the HDFS blocks in such a way that it will split on a linebreak.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Fokko